# Nodejs Request followed by Request - synchronization issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request, synchronous

I'm new to the world of callback hell, and have gotten a little stuck.  I'm doing some analytics work, so every time a function is called, I call a function which does a request.post to log the request on our server.  In each of those original functions, however, a request.get is made to return some information.  So, I am essentially calling a function that makes a request inside another function that needs to make a request after that one.  The code itself is a lot more complicated (and by complicated, I mean long and annoying) than I just described, so here's the dumbed-down version:

```
function myFunction(x, y, callback) {
    // variable declarations
    postFunction(a, b);
    // other logic for the function
    request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
        // request code here
        callback(somedata, otherFunctionThatDoesntMatterHere(blah));
    });
}

function postFunction(a, b) {
    // other logic for the function
    var dataToSend = "XML HERE";
    request.post({
        url: url,
        body: dataToSend,
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'text/xml'},
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode);
            }
            else if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log('POST RESPONSE: ', body);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

What's happening right now is that the post function doesn't return before the end of the main function.  I know this is part of node's asynchronous-ness, but I would like these to be executed synchronously. I am pretty sure I can solve this by adding a callback to the post function, but I'm not sure how.  I've tried many different approaches, but I'm afraid I'm not entirely understanding how this all works.  Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want it to be synchronous, then yes you would need to add a callback to the postFunction.

For example:

```
function myFunction(x, y, callback) {
 // variable declarations
 postFunction(a, b, function(err) {
   // other logic for the function
   //maybe check if "err" has a value here
    request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
      // request code here
      callback(somedata, otherFunctionThatDoesntMatterHere(blah));
    });
 });

}

function postFunction(a, b, next) {
 // other logic for the function
 var dataToSend = "XML HERE";
 request.post({
    url: url,
    body: dataToSend,
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'text/xml'},
    function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            next(error);
        }
        else if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode);
            next('Invalid Status Code Returned:' + response.statusCode);
        }
        else if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('POST RESPONSE: ', body);
            next(null);
        }
    }
 );
}
```

This puts the rest of the code you want to fire within the callback of the postFunction, requiring it to complete first before anything else fires. Of course this will increase overall runtime of the function, since it has to now wait before continuing to run. Be careful of locking the event loop if you're doing CPU intensive tasks.

Also, to combat the ugliness of callback hell, you can use something like async-waterfall to chain functions one after another: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall

Comment: I was literally about to post my solution which is almost identical to this.  I wish I saw this first haha.  Thank you :)